# LLMs for text generation

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, generative-models, text-generation, llm

We know that AI is rapidly growing. do we have any large language models (LLMs) to process images, pdf documents directly (fine-tune approach) for text generation tasks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are open multimodal LLMs that you can fine-tune yourself, like [LlaVa](https://github.com/haotian-liu/LLaVA), [NextGPT](https://github.com/NExT-GPT/NExT-GPT), [IDEFICS](https://huggingface.co/blog/idefics) or [SPHINX](https://github.com/Alpha-VLLM/LLaMA2-Accessory).

Closed multimodal LLMs like [GPT-4v](https://openai.com/research/gpt-4v-system-card) don't offer a way to fine-tune them yet.